# How to find element to click button in Python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

HTML:

```
<input class="loginButton fieldSpacing" onclick="loginBtnDisable();ajaxSubmitLogin()" value="Submit" style="cursor:pointer;text-align: center;" onkeypress="return loginTabEnter(this,event)">
```

Python code:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR(".loginButton.fieldSpacing")).click();
```

but got error msg as:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: HTML:''''<input class="loginButton fieldSpacing" onclick="loginBtnDisable();ajaxSubmitLogin()" value="Submit" style="cursor:pointer;text-align: center;" onkeypress="return loginTabEnter(this,event)">''''

Comment: Can try this xpath ```//input[@value='Submit']```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".loginButton.fieldSpacing").click();
```

EDIT:
Just for your information:
What you did wrong is that you called "By.CSS_SELECTOR" which is as string type object.

```py
By.CSS_SELECTOR(".loginButton.fieldSpacing")
```

Was the code resulting in the exception